# What tribal/regional Yemeni arabic dialects and/or modern south Arabian languages or crioles do SFO and OAK Bay Area Yemeni imigrants speak most?

Tags: arabic, dialects, semitic-languages

I think I've noticed near-homogeneity, in SF and Oakland bodegas. But there are reasons to doubt that.

I'm interested in:

1. The most common Yemeni lects (or three most commonly natively used, for native speakers of multiple varieties) among potential nearby corner-store native informants.
2. Those with most and least overlap/colearner-advantage, for speakers of Ethiosemitic languages.

Context: language geek here, choosing 2 or so other languages (including 1+ non-MSA Arabic dialects) to learn while learning Tigrinya, as my co-first Semitic language*s*. I have a penchant/predilection for conserved pronounced (e.g. accusative) terminal-nunnation case endings*, and complex or rare phonetic gems (phonemic articulatory/phonetic delicacies and/or large phonetic inventories and abstruse morphosyntax).

> - The main goal in this being to get some insight into the Quran, as the Prophet hallowed be his name, might imagine his great-grandparents might have pronounced it in the last still-nunnating pre-Quranic Medino-Arabian proto-Arabic speakers that they presumably would be.

Comment: Most of this post is impossible to follow. Bodegas are usually Spanish-speaking run establishments.

Comment: I've cleared up the grammar as best I can and swapped some terminology for more typical linguistic terminology, but in some places it was pretty garbled so it wasn't easy to interpret. If I've misinterpreted the question, Ayer, please clarify

Comment: “SFO”? “OAK”? .

Comment: It's airport codes

Answer (score 0):

Best I can tell, the question is "what language are Yemeni shopkeepers in the Bay Area likely speaking, if it's not English or Spanish". Most likely, Yemeni Arabic. Mehri and Soqotri are possible, but unlikely because they are highly regional, and Yemeni Arabic is the most-likely shared language for the area.

Within the umbrella of Yemeni Arabic, many dialects can be discerned. To figure out whether most shopkeepers speak Ta'izzi-Adeni, San'ani, Tihamiyya, Hadhrami or Yafi'i, you would first need an isogloss questionnaire that tells you the linguistic features that identify the particular dialects. Also, you need to figure out how to ask questions in a way that does not bias responses in favor of a particular dialect.